# Mac Permission Editing

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, file-management, file-permissions

I copied over some old files of a time machine backup on a USB drive. When I try and access a user's Desktop for example I get a "can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents"

How do I go about fixing that?

Comment: You just need to change the permissions to include your user account

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called BatChmod that will perform advanced permissions repairs.  Of course you can also use terminal commands but this is easier in a pinch.  I would start with Change ownership and privileges, Clear ACLs, and Unlock.  Apply it to all subfolders obviously.
http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

The users files are setup in a group for that user, not you. You can:

1. Change the owner of all the files to yourself
2. Change the group to a group that you are a part of
3. Add yourself to a group that has permissions to access the files to preserve permissions
4. Modify the permissions so that anyone can read and write the files

`1` will change the permissions of all the files so that you will become the owner

> chown youruser:youruser ~/path/to/directory

`2` will modify just the group of all the files to give you access without modifying the permissions

> chown :youruser ~/path/to/directory

`3` will modify your user, and add you to a group that has permissions to access the files

> usermod -aG somegroup youruser

`4` will change the permissions of all the files so that anyone can read / write / execute any file (not recommended)

> chmod 777 ~/path/to/directory

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!

Comment: @carpetsmoker, easy there killer, as I said, this is not recommended. Also note that I said path to directory, not file, 777 on a directory can be okay, like _/tmp_, but files should not be.

Comment: If It's not recommended, then why offer it as a possibly solution? ;-) You should never need it. And `/tmp` is indeed one of the very few exceptions, but **only** when the sticky bit is set (i.e. `chmod 1777`)

Comment: To be fair, this was posted 3 years ago. I have done muchhhhh more UNIX since then, I can change this up when I get off mobile.